# Fragment transaction animations lost when rotating screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I show animation when user navigates away from fragment. For that I am using [setCustomAndimations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) of support package.
"popEnter" and "popExit" work fine, but they are lost after activity gets rotated, 
i.e. after rotation popping fragment happens without the animation.

Fragment creation in activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState == null) { // activity started for the first time, no fragment attached yet
        fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(params);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(0, 0, // enter animations, not important here
        // when popping fragment -> these are lost on rotation
        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right); 
        ft.add(R.id.content, fragment, MY_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

Is there way / workaround to keep animating "popping out" of fragment after rotation ?

Answer (score -1):

I found a temporarily solution for this problem [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25994) (answer #3)

fix this by adding:
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
to your FragmentActivity in the manifest.

There are of course problems, when you i.e. inflate different layouts in your onCreateView, depending on the screen size. So thats also not a final answer.

Edit: you can create your own backstack:

public final class MBackStack {

```
public static Stack<Fragment> fragStack = new Stack<>();

private MBackStack(){}

public static void addFragment(Fragment frag){
    fragStack.push(frag);
}

public static Fragment getFragment(){
    if (fragStack.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    fragStack.pop();
    Fragment fragment = fragStack.peek();
    return fragment;
}

public static int getStackSize(){
    return fragStack.size();
}

public static void clearStack(){
    while (fragStack.size()!=0){
        fragStack.pop();
    }
}
```

}

Now instead of

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

You can add:

```
YOURFRAGMENT yf = new YOURFRAGMENT();
MBackStack.addFragment(yf);
ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, dts);
ft.commit();
```

And in your main activity you can override your onbackpressed:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(MBackStack.getStackSize()>1){
        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_left, R.anim.out_right);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, MBackStack.getFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }else{
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.slide_bottom_out);
    }
}
```

I have tried it, and it works fine.

Comment: This will prevent orientation changes altogether, I still want to keep them. Thanks, anyways, your link gave me impression that google is going to fix it someday in supportlib which is a good news !